# Java List addressing first and last elements

Tags: java, collections

Is there any better way to access the first and last locations on a java list other than

```
curr.set(curr.size()-1, 10);
curr.get(curr.size()-1);
curr.set(0, 10);
curr.get(0);
```

Where curr can be assumed to be a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `LinkedList` you can get the last and first elements.

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
linkedList.add("element");

String last = linkedList.getLast();
String first = linkedList.getFirst();
```

Both operations are constant time, but a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown if the list is empty.

Comment: But then i assume get would be O(n). I guess what I am really looking for is the convenience of a C++ vector (which supports a front() and back() along with constant time access to random indices). From what i can tell that doesn't exist. Just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to use Google Guava's `Iterables` [util class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html);

```
Iterables.getFirst(myList);
Iterables.getLast(myList);
```

On top of this, it has a safe logic where you can give a default value in case the list is empty/null.

```
Iterables.getFirst(myList, defaultVal);
Iterables.getLast(myList, defaultVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding retrieving the first and last elements, Java 21 added methods [`getFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#getFirst()) and [`getLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#getLast()) to the `List` interface.

```java
curr.getLast();
curr.getFirst();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case that first and last are the only elements you actually access I would suggest that you use a `java.util.Deque<T>` instead of a `List`.

Comment: A Deque doesn't allow setting the first and last element. Only inserting at the head/tail of the queue.

Comment: That is easily solved by using the RemoveLast and RemoveFirst before inserting with AddLast and AddFirst.